# Core Plot cutting off data in bar style

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, core-plot

I have a core plot based bar chart and all of my labels fit, Barely but they do fit, but i cannot get the corresponding data to not be split in half for the last month (June).

I've tried messing with the right bounds but that did nothing, any ideas?

my formatting:

```
    graph                               = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTStocksTheme]];
    self.hostedGraph                    = graph;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder   = NO;
    graph.paddingLeft                   = 0.0f;
    graph.paddingTop                    = 0.0f;
    graph.paddingRight                  = 0.0f;
    graph.paddingBottom                 = 0.0f;

    CPTMutableLineStyle *borderLineStyle    = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    borderLineStyle.lineColor               = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    borderLineStyle.lineWidth               = 2.0f;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle     = borderLineStyle;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop          = 10.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight        = 20.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom       = 80.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft         = 55.0;

    //Add plot space
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace       = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    //CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.newPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.delegate              = self;

    //MAX Y

    int TOP = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02f", highestPoint] intValue];
    plotSpace.yRange                = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(TOP +5)];

    //MAX X
    plotSpace.xRange                = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(-1) 
                                                                   length:CPTDecimalFromInt(numOfBars)];
#pragma mark - Grid Lines
    //Grid line styles
    CPTMutableLineStyle *majorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth            = 0.75;
    majorGridLineStyle.lineColor            = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1];
    CPTMutableLineStyle *minorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    minorGridLineStyle.lineWidth            = 0.25;
    minorGridLineStyle.lineColor            = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1];

    //Axes
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
#pragma mark - X- Axis
    //X axis
    CPTXYAxis *x                    = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal   = CPTDecimalFromInt(0);
    x.majorIntervalLength           = CPTDecimalFromInt(1);
    x.minorTicksPerInterval         = 0;
    x.labelingPolicy                = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    x.majorGridLineStyle            = majorGridLineStyle;
    x.axisConstraints               = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];

    //X labels
    int labelLocations = 0;
    NSMutableArray *customXLabels = [NSMutableArray array];
#pragma mark - X- Axis Labels
    for (NSString *day in xAxis) {
        CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:day textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
        newLabel.tickLocation   = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:labelLocations] decimalValue];
        newLabel.offset         = x.labelOffset + x.majorTickLength;
        newLabel.rotation       = M_PI / 4;
        [customXLabels addObject:newLabel];
        labelLocations++;

    }
    x.axisLabels                    = [NSSet setWithArray:customXLabels];
    NSLog(@"%@", xAxis);

    //Y axis
#pragma mark - Y- Axis
    CPTXYAxis *y            = axisSet.yAxis;
    //y.title                 = @"Profit";
    //y.titleOffset           = 40.0f;
    y.labelingPolicy        = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    y.majorGridLineStyle    = majorGridLineStyle;
    y.minorGridLineStyle    = minorGridLineStyle;

    //THIS WAS 0
    y.axisConstraints       = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];

    //Create a bar line style
    CPTMutableLineStyle *barLineStyle   = [[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc] init];
    barLineStyle.lineWidth              = 1.0;
    barLineStyle.lineColor              = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    CPTMutableTextStyle *whiteTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    whiteTextStyle.color                = [CPTColor whiteColor];

    //Plot
    BOOL firstPlot = YES;
    for (NSString *set in [[sets allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]) {
        CPTBarPlot *plot        = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor blueColor] horizontalBars:NO];
        plot.lineStyle          = barLineStyle;
        CGColorRef color        = ((UIColor *)[sets objectForKey:set]).CGColor;
        plot.fill               = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithCGColor:color]];
        if (firstPlot) {
            plot.barBasesVary   = NO;
            firstPlot           = NO;
        } else {
            plot.barBasesVary   = YES;
        }
        plot.barWidth           = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.8f);
        plot.barsAreHorizontal  = NO;
        plot.dataSource         = self;
        plot.identifier         = set;
        [graph addPlot:plot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
    }
    }
```

Also not too important but how do i remove the black corners?

[image: Core Plot Cut off]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bars are centered at the x locations which is why you only see half of the last bar. Increase the length of the `xRange` to make room for the other half of the bar. Increase it by 0.5 to have the bar end near the edge of the plot area or 1.0 for symmetry with the first bar.